# Leaflet markercluster group and layer control not working

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to add clustering and layer control to filter markers on my map. After reading older posts on this issue, the code that was marked as the right answer looks like this. However, no matter how I change it, it does not work on my map.

```
var parent= new L.MarkerClusterGroup().addTo(map);
var overlay={}
overlay["Markers A"]=L.featureGroup.subGroup(parent,aPoints).addTo(map);
overlay["Markers B"]=L.featureGroup.subGroup(parent,bPoints).addTo(map);

control = L.control.layers(null, overlay, {collapsed: false });
control.addTo(map);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code sample you show seems to be fine indeed. But there dozens of other potential reasons for it not working in your specific situation (loading libraries, assignment of variables, etc.). Without further detail on that situation, it is almost impossible to help you further.

Comment: I am calling the leaflet,markercluster and feature group libraries. Here's the full script that I am using. http://next.plnkr.co/edit/nA9AetOM5ZFFQZGs?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I was having was that L.featureGroup.subGroup takes in an array of markers as it's second parameters therefore, aPoints needed to be [aPoints].